# Challenge: compare chemical names with sort and join

Tags: bash, python-2.7, csv, awk

### What I have:

A file containing names and assay readouts in `TSV` or `CSV` format, `data.txt`:

```
Name,readout_1,readout_2,readout_3
A,98.0,-12.3,0.9
G,32.1,9.1,34.5
X,45.1,-2.3,56.7
```

Another file containing names and Compound IDs in `TSV` or `CSV` format, `ref.txt`:

```
Name,Compound_ID
A,1234
B,1235
C,1236
...
Z,3456
```

### What I want:

I need to add the Compound ID to `data.txt` in an additional column based on matching names, i.e.:

```
Name,readout_1,readout_2,readout_3,Compound_ID
A,98.0,-12.3,0.9,1234
G,32.1,9.1,34.5,1240
X,45.1,-2.3,56.7,3454
```

### The Challenge:

I'm dealing with chemical names that can be very long and can contain dashes, space characters, commas, parentheses, numbers ..., e.g.

```
2-acetoxybenzoic acid
N-(4-hydroxyphenyl)ethanamide
2-[(2S,5R,8S,11S)-5-benzyl-11-{3-[(diaminomethylidene)amino]propyl}-7-methyl-3,6,9,12,15-pentaoxo-8-(propan-2-yl)-1,4,7,10,13-pentaazacyclopentadecan-2-yl]acetic acid
```

The names are present in both files; I haven't been able to find a working solution though.  I tried using `sort` and `join`, which works until a name contains a space character, then `join` complains that the offending line is not sorted.

If possible, I'd prefer a solution in `bash`, `python`, or `awk` since I have a rudimentary understanding here.

### Edit:

Apologies for being unclear in my posting. Some clarifications:

I use `TSV`, but thought it would be clearer in the examples to use `CSV` since a comma is easier discernible than a tab.

Apologies for not using actual names in the examples; again, this was done in order to keep the examples simple. The third example name shows just how long the names can be, and this is not even a particularly long one.

Lastly, I think my issues are rooted in the space characters in some chemical names. I'm not aware of an option to ignore space when using `join`.

Comment: `I use TSV, but thought it would be clearer in the examples to use CSV since a comma is easier discernible than a tab.`. Doing that probably turned this into a VASTLY different problem since the only problem you had in your question was that your chemical names could contain the separator (a comma). Can your chemical names contain tab characters? If so then use the awk solution I posted, if not then use the join solution @mauro posted. In both cases just set the separator in the script to a tab instead of a comma.

Comment: No, the names do not contain `TAB` characters. As mentioned in my original post and the edit, my issue is related to `SPACE` characters, not commas, since `join` doesn't recognize name with `SPACE` character(s) as sorted. I haven't thought of enclosing the names in quotes prior to executing `join`; will try that when back at work on Tuesday.

Comment: Like with any other tool that uses "whitespace" as a delimiter by default, when you tell `join` to use a **specific** character as a delimiter, `join` couldn't care less about blank chars or any other characters that aren't that specific delimiter character. Just use `join -t $'\t' file1 file2`.

Answer (score 1):

This simple `bash` command should work:

```
$ join -t , data.txt ref.txt
Name,readout_1,readout_2,readout_3,Compound_ID
A,98.0,-12.3,0.9,1234
G,32.1,9.1,34.5,1240
X,45.1,-2.3,56.7,3454
```

Comment: He actually said input files can be either TSV or CSV. Then he (Markus) adds towards the end that Names can have spaces, commas, parentheses, etc. Maybe commas AND spaces? Who knows? I hope OP will use TSV if names contain commas...

Answer (score 1):

The only problem you have is that your real names can contain commas while your input files are comma-separated. You didn't represent that at all in your sample input, nor do the ids across your 2 input files match so here's something more like what you should have posted for sample input and expected output:

```
$ cat data.txt
Name,readout_1,readout_2,readout_3
A,3,17,35
A,3,98.0,-12.3,0.9
G,2,7,32.1,9.1,34.5
X,Y,Z,1,45.1,-2.3,56.7

$ cat ref.txt
Name,Compound_ID
A,9999
A,3,1234
G,2,7,1235
X,Y,Z,1,3456
```

i.e. the 4 "Names" in the above can contain commas themselves and are `A`, `A,3`, `G,2,7`, and `X,Y,Z,1`, and here's the script plus output:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 { numVals = NF-1 }
{
    match($0,"(.*),(([^,]+(,|$)){"numVals"})$",a)
    name = a[1]
    vals = a[2]
}
NR==FNR { ref[name] = vals; next }
{ print "\"" name "\"", vals, ref[name] }

$ awk -f tst.awk ref.txt data.txt
"Name",readout_1,readout_2,readout_3,Compound_ID
"A",3,17,35,9999
"A,3",98.0,-12.3,0.9,1234
"G,2,7",32.1,9.1,34.5,1235
"X,Y,Z,1",45.1,-2.3,56.7,3456
```

Note that I added quotes around the `name` field on output so the result is a valid CSV file.

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`. With other awks you'd just use 2 `sub()`s:

```
name = vals = $0
sub("(,[^,]+){"numVals"}$","",name)
sub("^([^,]+,){"NF-numVals"}","",vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody who responded, and to Ed for insisting that `join` couldn't care less about spaces.

My issue was that the data was not sorted properly, which caused `join` to report that my input wasn't sorted; see below.

Data File:

```
$ cat test_data.txt
Acebutolol hydrochloride    0.904   0.146   0.134   -0.196
Aconitine   -0.558  -0.471  -0.13   -0.332
```

Reference file sorted with incorrect order:

```
$ cat test_ref_S1.txt
ACACETIN    CDRD-00116180-01
ACACETIN DIACETATE  CDRD-00118610-01
ACEBUTOLOL HYDROCHLORIDE    CDRD-00115573-01
ACECLOFENAC CDRD-00115696-01
ACEMETACIN  CDRD-00115788-01
ACENOCOUMAROL   CDRD-00115657-01
ACETAMIDE   CDRD-00116997-01
ACETAMINOPHEN   CDRD-00116365-01
ACETYL ISOALLOGAMBOGIC ACID CDRD-00118740-01
ACETYL ISOGAMBOGIC ACID CDRD-00119007-01
ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER CDRD-00118256-01
ACETYLSALICYLIC ACID    CDRD-00117028-01
ACETYLSALICYLSALICYLIC ACID CDRD-00115640-01
ACETYLTHIOCHOLINE CHLORIDE  CDRD-00117030-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN    CDRD-00117996-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHANAMIDE   CDRD-00118894-01
ACEXAMIC ACID   CDRD-00118338-01
ACIVICIN    CDRD-00116623-01
ACONITIC ACID   CDRD-00117968-01
ACONITINE   CDRD-00116111-01
```

Now sort properly:

```
$ sort -k1 -t $'\t' -V -f test_ref_S1.txt > test_ref_S2.txt
$ cat test_ref_S2.txt 
ACACETIN    CDRD-00116180-01
ACACETIN DIACETATE  CDRD-00118610-01
ACEBUTOLOL HYDROCHLORIDE    CDRD-00115573-01
ACECLOFENAC CDRD-00115696-01
ACEMETACIN  CDRD-00115788-01
ACENOCOUMAROL   CDRD-00115657-01
ACETAMIDE   CDRD-00116997-01
ACETAMINOPHEN   CDRD-00116365-01
ACETYLSALICYLIC ACID    CDRD-00117028-01
ACETYLSALICYLSALICYLIC ACID CDRD-00115640-01
ACETYLTHIOCHOLINE CHLORIDE  CDRD-00117030-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHANAMIDE   CDRD-00118894-01
ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN    CDRD-00117996-01
ACETYL ISOALLOGAMBOGIC ACID CDRD-00118740-01
ACETYL ISOGAMBOGIC ACID CDRD-00119007-01
ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER CDRD-00118256-01
ACEXAMIC ACID   CDRD-00118338-01
ACIVICIN    CDRD-00116623-01
ACONITIC ACID   CDRD-00117968-01
ACONITINE   CDRD-00116111-01
```

Check the difference:

```
$ diff test_ref_S1.txt test_ref_S2.txt 
9,11d8
< ACETYL ISOALLOGAMBOGIC ACID   CDRD-00118740-01
< ACETYL ISOGAMBOGIC ACID   CDRD-00119007-01
< ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER   CDRD-00118256-01
15d11
< ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN  CDRD-00117996-01
16a13,16
> ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN  CDRD-00117996-01
> ACETYL ISOALLOGAMBOGIC ACID   CDRD-00118740-01
> ACETYL ISOGAMBOGIC ACID   CDRD-00119007-01
> ACETYL TYROSINE ETHYL ESTER   CDRD-00118256-01
```

Finally, join the files:

```
$ join -a1 -1 1 -2 1 -t $'\t' -i test_data.txt test_ref_S2.txt > out.txt
join: test_ref_S2.txt:13: is not sorted: ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN   CDRD-00117996-01
$ cat out.txt 
Acebutolol hydrochloride    0.904   0.146   0.134   -0.196  CDRD-00115573-01
Aconitine   -0.558  -0.471  -0.13   -0.332  CDRD-00116111-01
```

ACETYLTRYPTOPHAN is not sorted properly as it should be above ACETYLTRYPTOPHANAMIDE, but I haven't been able to figure this one out.